# Is it possible to configure CKFinder as just a file browser without any upload functionality?

Tags: ckeditor, ckfinder

I want to be able to click on the image icon in CKEditor and be able to browser the local file system. I would like the chosen file to be passed to the editor just like the standard URL is. I want to use the [base64image](http://ckeditor.com/addon/base64image) plugin to embed the image inline.

I have tried using CKFinder but, when I click the `Browse Server` button in the `Image Properties` dialog, I get an empty window with just 'run();' in the centre.

Answer (score 2):

To enable CKFinder in read-only (gallery) mode, set the [`readOnly`](http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3/#!/api/CKFinder.Config-cfg-readOnly) configuration option to `true` and pass it as a configruation option to the [`CKFinder.setupCKEditor`](http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3/#!/api/CKFinder-method-setupCKEditor) function:

```
CKFinder.setupCKEditor( editor, {
    readOnly: true
} );
```

This will disable the possibility to modify anything.

If you only want to disable uploads, you can [disable modules](http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3/#!/api/CKFinder.Config-cfg-removeModules) related to upload operations:

```
CKFinder.setupCKEditor( editor, {
    removeModules: 'FormUpload,Html5Upload,UploadFileButton'
} );
```

The second thing is to change [Access Control settings](http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3-php/configuration.html#configuration_options_accessControl) in the server side connector by setting `'FILE_CREATE'` to `false` so the uploads will be disabled also on the server side.

Comment: Doesn't seem to help me. I don't want to go into readonly mode. I want to open a file browser which navigates to local files only and returns the URL of the chosen (image). Perhaps I'm missing something very simple but I'm not able to open a simple file browser